# How can I come back with my old ID?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am Persian Cat:

https://english.stackexchange.com/users/37324/persian-cat

How can I come back with my own old Id?.. I have forgotten the e mail address which I used before and its password!.. But I remember that I exchanged many information with admins by this e mail address:

divar_neveshte@yahoo.com

I would like to come back after one year and unfortunately faced with this problem that the site cannot remember me any more with my old Id and I have to make another one that I don't like!..

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Although I don't know the answer to this question, I'm certain that you are much more likely to find it at the Meta Stack Exchange site at http://meta.stackexchange.com/ than you are to find it here.

Comment: I have no reputations in this new Id so I can't post anything in the meta by myself.I suggest you to take a look at rules of this site before answering a question that you don't know and can't help. It can save your energy! :)

Comment: Sorry admins! I didn't get it. It means you have no solution or you don't know how to say that? Could you please explain it? Only please relax! :))

Comment: Humm.. I am waiting! Be relax and answer it when you felt you can handle it without being nervous. It is very easy! I only need my account information to be able send posts with my own Id and all my 437 reputation. You don't seem friendly! Are you OK?:)

Comment: I don't really understand why three people have downvoted this question, but since there are no explanatory comments, I can only suppose the three *upvotes* for pyrAmider's comment are significant. I realise in principle OP's problem could arise on *any* SE site, so arguably ["meta meta"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) is the place to post. But it's not much of a way to welcome back a long-lost returning prodigal son. Whatever - good luck with the contact form, @Persian Cat!

Comment: @PersianCat You should remove the email address from your post or bots cruising the web may find it and send you spam. Additionally I assume you will be using it as evidence to re-gain your old account. Everyone who has viewed this page now has that same evidence and could use it as part of their arsenal to try claiming your old account. Just a thought mate :)

Answer (score 6):

Please fill out the [contact form](https://english.stackexchange.com/contact#) providing any evidence that you have that that account is yours.